# How do I send a variable declared in JavaScript to the server side PHP script so that I can perform a SQL query using that variable?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is my JavaScript code:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var prikey = (i+1);
            //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prikey;
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) 
{
    //some code here
}
```

Now, I want to transfer prikey from this JavaScript file to the server-side PHP file.

The PHP code is

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT countries FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

I want to integrate the transferred prikey variable such that I will be able to query the database in the following way:

```
$sql="SELECT countries FROM $tbl_name where id=$prikey";
```

where $prikey is where I store the value gotten from the JavaScript file.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: First of all where is the variable being passed in the javascript. You need to actually add it to the end of your GET Url. Such as ?id=primarykey then use $_GET['id'] to fetch it. Then add your where clause into your query with a binding param such as where id= :mykey and then use mysqli bindparam function to pass the $_GET value into that and just fetch results back and send back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `prikey` as a parameter to the GET url.

**Javascript:**

```
// The request is inside of a function so that each 
// xmlhttp is a different object
function sendRequest(prikey) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.status === 200 || xmlhttp.status === 304) 
            {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url + '?prikey=' + prikey, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
// Send the requests
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // Pass it the prikey
    sendRequest(i + 1);
}

function myFunction(response) 
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

**And in your PHP code, get it through the $_GET array:**

```
// Get the variable sent through the Ajax request
$prikey = $_GET['prikey'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT countries FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $prikey";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// echo the result so that your JavaScript code gets the response
// Again, ignore if you've already done this
echo $result;
```

Comment: This code cannot work as I want it to. But the '?prikey=' + prikey should help. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, what do you want exactly? Do you want to send a second AJAX request to another URL, along with the prikey?

Comment: Yes. So, the code should run in a way that the ajax call is executed 5 times (because the for loop is that long) and every time it is executed, the sql query should retrieve data corresponding to the $prikey value.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's going on with my code. Only the 5th value gets displayed. I checked the JS console; my code is just retrieving the 5th value and ignoring the first four. May be it's an issue with the "//some code here" part. Will debug and see. Thanks for the update, though.

Comment: Hmm, are all requests being sent? Check the network tab. Also, the `new XMLHttpRequest()` has to be inside of the loop, otherwise the requests cancel out. No problem.

Comment: All the requests are being sent. Yes, I have kept it inside the loop.

Comment: So here's what's happening. I am tracking the network log, and every request (from prikey 1 to 5) is being sent, but the _Time_ column in the Network tab is logged as 'pending' and is updated to time taken to retrieve the data only after for loop is exited. And I guess, that is the reason why just the fifth request (because it is the latest) is being displayed. But I got what I needed, so thanks @Alfonso Garnett

Comment: I think it was a problem with the code I posted, sorry. The `onreadystate` function was being 'overwritten' by every new request in the loop, so only the last one would execute. It is now encapsulated within a function, so that each request is a different object and the `onreadystate` property doesn't get overwritten. This should now work. Also, notice that prikey is no longer a global variable. If you want to use that var elsewhere other than for the AJAX request, you can re-declare it as global (outside of the functions). Sorry for that. Good luck, and thanks to you.

Comment: And please, let me know if any further issues arise.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! I wish I could vote up once again :)

Comment: Great! Haha, it's okay, I'm glad I could help, you're welcome. :)